# How to define (overwrite the default value) the host in a Symfony application?

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony 5.4 backend app, which acts mostly as an API, but it also has an EasyAdmin frontend. The server is behind a reverse proxy (in our case it is AWS API Gateway) and a Load Balancer. The server hosting the app has its own internal domain address (let's say that it is `symfony.internal.com`) that is not accessible from an outside world. The reverse proxy has a domain (let's say `www.example.com`).

Now what happens is that the EasyAdmin bundle asks Symfony to generate URLs for its menus. Symfony checks the host domain, and gets `symfony.internal.com`. This is useless, because if anyone clicks on an URL like this, there is going to be no DNS to resolve this.

The Symfony app culd get the correct domain (`www.example.com`) from the `Origin` header, but I would actually prefer to set it in the `env` as that way I will be able to force Symfony to use the domain that I validate.

Is there a way to do it?

The other thing is that the same thing (generation of an URL with the internal domain) happens, when authentication is performed. On a successful login to EasyAdmin, the redirect goes to the internal domain.

What I understand is that using `trusted_proxies` and `trusted_hosts` is not the way to go here - the traffic will be only from the API Gateway and I it doesn't have a fixed IP address. Also, I don't need to whitelist anything. I need to overwrite the host.

I tried to set `app.host` in the services, but it doesn't work.

Comment: does this help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-commands

Comment: @Jakumi Unfortunately no. When I try to log in to the EasyAdmin, I'm still getting the local URL in the `session` property of the request

Comment: There is a thing called the RequestContext, which essentially decides, what the base url is going to be. The RequestContext will by default be filled by the request, that includes the base url / domain. So I see some possible solutions. One solution would be to add [Kernel Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) that will fetch the RequestContext from the router (for example) and set the baseurl according to your config value. Another (dirty) solution would be, to overwrite the baseUrl somehow on the Request, before the RequestContext is created (probably bad).

Comment: the Router has a method [getContext](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/41da7e8b1d270e65c838fd83207faf5712cbd9ae/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php#L204) for grabbing it, and setContext if you want to override it entirely with a new context.

Comment: @Jakumi Thank you for these options. I'll look into them as soon as I'm back in front of my pc. The first one (clean one) has a disadvantage that the listener will be checking all requests and 90% of them are APIs which don't care about host URL

Comment: true, but considering the amount of code in general, the overhead is probably miniscule. I don't exactly know, if it would work, but you could tell the Container to provide an extended RequestContext with a preset base url ... however, this would require more knowledge about the service container, and it still might not work. but it would reduce the overhead. depending on your eagerness to possibly waste time ... ;oD